# How do i fix this " TypeError: listen() missing 1 required positional argument: 'source' "?

Tags: python, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

In regards to building a speech recognition platform i have come across the following problem of **TypeError: listen() missing 1 required positional argument: 'source'**,Can someone please walk me through correcting this.Thanks.

```
import speech_recognition

recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer
with speech_recognition.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say something")
    audio = recognizer.listen(source)

print("Google thinks you said: ")
print(recognizer.recognize_google(audio))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
```

instead of,

```
recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks it helped but now im left with another error : if not isinstance(actual_result, dict) or len(actual_result.get("alternative", [])) == 0: raise UnknownValueError()
speech_recognition.UnknownValueError

Comment: Be sure to check your audio input, As Your code is unable to get any input it returns error saying empty list []

Comment: are you referring to my microphone? To check if its functional?

Comment: It can be either no audio or too much noise hence you're getting unknown value error. To reduce ambient noise you can try 'recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)' before listen(source)